# ¿Como hago para que un fragment termine antes de la barra inferior? - Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Tengo un fragment con un listView y no me muestra el ultimo elemento porque esta debajo de la barra inferior de Android, como puedo ponerle el margen inferior para que no se ponga debajo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

fragment_list.xml

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="layout.fragmentList">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listaMultas"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: Listview por naturaleza es Scrolleable por lo que no es necesario ponerle el scroll, intenta quitandolo por favor y deja solo el relative

Comment: @Ajeno cuando hago eso, deja de funcionar el scroll :/

Comment: ¿Al fragment si le estas añadiendo la propiedad android:layout_gravity="start"?

Comment: @Ajeno no, que hace esa propiedad?

Comment: podrias agregar el xml que contiene a fragment_list.xml?

Comment: ya esta @pablobu!

Answer (score 0):

ejemplo

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.tritonix.scotproyect.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listaMultas"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: la verdad no se porque no te funciona a mi si me funciona asi

Comment: el scroll si me funciona, lo que pasa es que el ultimo elemento de la vista queda tapado por la barra inferior (la barra de navegacion)

Comment: que sucede cuando intentas hacer scroll hasta el final de la lista?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberias simplificar fragment_list.xml al siguiente contenido:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listaMultas"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: lo probare, aviso que tal me va